# RxJS Subject closing subscriptions automatically when finished

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two subjects exposed in a service, so that I can render the values in the subject and render them on my page.

One of those subjects receives the information correctly, but the second one automatically closes the subscriptions and I cannot retrieve the data anymore.

This is my code:

```
// service.ts
  clientSubject: Subject<any>;
  jobSubject: Subject<any>;

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private jobService: JobService) {
    this.clientSubject = new Subject();
    this.jobSubject = new Subject();
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.clientService.getClients()
    .pipe(
      map(clients => clients.map(
        client => this.jobService.getJobs(client.clientId)
          .pipe(
            map(jobs => jobs.map(job => ({client, job})))
          )
          .subscribe(this.jobSubject)
        )
    ))
    .subscribe(this.clientSubject);
  }
```

this is the code in my component:

```
  clients: any;
  jobs: any;

  constructor(private invoiceService: InvoiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.invoiceService.clientSubject.subscribe(d => {
      this.clients = d;
      console.log(this.clients);
    });

    this.invoiceService.jobSubject.subscribe(d => {
      this.jobs = d;
      console.log(this.jobs);
    });

    this.invoiceService.fetchData();
  }
```

This is what the console logs:

```
### this.jobs data ###
invoices.component.ts:25 
[{…}]
0: {client: {…}, job: {…}}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)


### this.clients data ###
invoices.component.ts:19 
(2) [SubjectSubscriber, SubjectSubscriber]
0: SubjectSubscriber {closed: true, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}
1: SubjectSubscriber {closed: true, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Why is the `this.clients` data being overridden by SubjectSubscribers based on the implementation in `fetchData`?

The `jobService.getJobs(client.clientId)` returns an observable with the following format:

```
[{jobId: 1, name: 'blabla', items: []}]
```

the `jobService.getClients()` returns an observable with the following format:

```
[{clientId: 1, name: 'blabla', isParent: false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now. Map is converting an array of clients into an array of subscriptions. That's what `clients.map([...]`. Is doing. Maybe what's confusing you is that `.subscribe` returns a value? Like this:

```
const valueReturnedBySubscribe = anyObservable.subscribe(LAMBDA);
console.log(valueReturnedBySubscribe);
```

output:

```
SubjectSubscriber {closed: true, [...]
```

Try this instead:

```
fetchData(): void {
  this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
    tap(clients => clients.forEach(
      client => this.jobService.getJobs(client.clientId)
        .pipe(
          map(jobs => jobs.map(job => ({client, job})))
        )
        .subscribe(this.jobSubject)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(this.clientSubject);
}
```

`tap` doesn't change your stream at all, and you don't seem to want your subscriptions objects anyway. Not sure why you're using map, but it doesn't look like you need it.

---

#### Update

It probably makes the most sense to have jobSubject subscribe to clientSubject since new clients always means queries for new jobs. That could look something like:

```
clientSubject: Subject<any>;
jobSubject: Subject<any>;

constructor(private clientService: ClientService, private jobService: JobService) {

  this.clientSubject = new Subject();
  this.jobSubject = new Subject();

  this.clientSubject.pipe(
    map(clients => clients.map(
      client => jobService.getJobs(client.clientId).pipe(
        map(jobs => jobs.map(job => ({client, job})))
      )
    )),
    mergeMap(jobs => merge(jobs))
  ).subscribe(this.jobSubject);
}

fetchData(): void {
  this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(this.clientSubject);
}
```

#### Aside:

Right now, your subjects (clientSubject, and jobSubject) are short-lived. They complete when one of the streams they subscribe to completes (or errors). If you want to avoid this, you can subscribe only to the values and not to the source stream's `complete()` and `error()` messages

All you would need to do is change:

```
this.clientSubject/*...code...*/subscribe(this.jobSubject);
to
this.clientSubject/*...code...*/subscribe(this.jobSubject.next);
```

and

```
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(this.clientSubject);
to
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(this.clientSubject.next);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues here

1. You're returning a subscription from the `map(clients...` that is later pushed to the `this.clientSubject`.
2. Multiple subscriptions are triggered for the array returned from the `getClients()` function. Instead you could `forkJoin` function to trigger multiple observables in parallel.
3. You could `switchMap` to chain observables instead of nested subscriptions.

Try the following

```js
fetchData(): void {
  this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
    tap(clients => this.clientSubject.next(clients)), // <-- emit to `clientSubject` using `tap` operator
    switchMap(clients => forkJoin(clients.map(client => // <-- use `forkJoin` to trigger multiple observables in parallel
      this.jobService.getJobs(client.clientId).pipe(
        map(jobs => jobs.map(job => ({client, job})))
      )
    )))
  ).subscribe(
    jobs => this.jobSubject.next(jobs)
  );
}
```

One difference is, the `jobSubject` will now emit an array of jobs of form `[{client, job}, {client, job}, ...]` instead of each job individually.

#### Update: emit on each source notification

You could use `tap` operator's `next`, `error` and `complete` callbacks to emit each corresponding notification to the respective subject.

```js
fetchData(): void {
  this.clientService.getClients().pipe(
    tap({ // <-- emit to `clientSubject` using `tap` operator
      next: clients => this.clientSubject.next(clients),
      error: error => this.clientSubject.next(error),
      complete: () => this.clientSubject.complete()
    }),
    switchMap(clients => forkJoin(clients.map(client => // <-- use `forkJoin` to trigger multiple observables in parallel
      this.jobService.getJobs(client.clientId).pipe(
        map(jobs => jobs.map(job => ({client, job}))),
        tap({
          next: jobs => this.jobSubject.next(jobs),
          error: error => this.jobSubject.error(error),
          complete: () => this.jobSubject.complete()  // <-- BAD IDEA! SEE BELOW
        })
      )
    )))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

But, emitting `complete` to a Subject essentially closes it. You cannot emit to it anymore and the future notifications will be ignored. So I wouldn't advice `this.jobSubject.complete()` in the `tap` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Unlike `observable.subscribe(subject)`, this doesn't pass `error()` or `complete()` emissions on to his subjects.

Comment: @MrkSef: I've updated the answer to emit both source observables using `tap` for corresponding types of notifications.

Comment: Yeah, it's always a fine dance of "Should I answer exactly what the poster was asking, or should I answer what I think they meant to ask." - I suspect you're right that he doesn't want his subjects to complete the moment a source observable completes.